# WP Featured Image URI instead of Custom Field

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am in a situation with a theme where I can't rely on custom-fields in wordpress and need to use the "featured image" feature instead.

This is the code that calls the custom field

```
<?php $thumbnail_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post-image', true); ?>
```

I can't find any documentation on "featured image" in the Wordpress codex, but is it possible to call the url of the featured image of a page in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you going
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

**Edit:**

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
$image_src = $image_attributes[0];
```

Comment: Playing with this, I am only able to get a image element without a src attribute, wondering how this is going to work.

Comment: I added the size argument to wp_get_attachment_image_src and it worked like a charm. Thanks!